# File Not Found Exception in Java even if file is there in directory

Tags: java

I am getting `File Not Found Exception` in Java even if file is there in directory.
Please find the details as follow.

After adding `System.out.println(csvConfPropertiesigFile.getAbsolutePath());`
 getting path of file as `C:\Users\abhishek.alone\workspace\project\abhi.properties`  but when I am searching this file at above path it is not there. It is at `C:\Users\abhishek.alone\workspace\project\src`

Please suggest...

Comment: If file is in project\ how you will get it in project\src?

Comment: A `File` or a `Path` is the location where a file could be.  How you fix this depends on which path is correct and how easily it is to correct it.

Comment: Same file might be present in two locations?

Comment: File is in C:\Users\abhishek.alone\workspace\project\src...

Comment: There is only one file

Comment: I am not using path there directly... I am doing csvFileName="abhi.properties"  and after that File csvConfPropertiesigFile = new File(csvFileName);

Comment: If you're not specifying the path explicitly, it will be calculated relative to the working directory when the program is running. Looks like you're not running the program in the correct directory.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help . I got it now :)